# $$A_{ij} B_{ji}$$ does not render correctly in remarkjs slide with mathjax

Tags: javascript, markdown, mathjax

I'm preparing a presentation slide using remark.js with mathjax. $$A_{ij}$$ is rendered properly, however not able to render $$A_{ij} B_{ji}$$ correctly.

I guess is the problem is the single-underscore also used as italic in markdown, I am not sure how to get around with this. Help is much appreciated. I have the minimalist code below. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="source">

$$A_{ij}$$

$$A_{ij} B_{ji}$$ 


    </textarea>
    <script src="http://gnab.github.io/remark/downloads/remark-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML&delayStartupUntil=configured" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var slideshow = remark.create();

    // Setup MathJax
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
        skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre']
        }
    });
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
        $(MathJax.Hub.getAllJax()).map(function(index, elem) {
            return(elem.SourceElement());
        }).parent().addClass('has-jax');
    });

    MathJax.Hub.Configured();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014573/mathjax-how-to-deal-with-this-strange-behavior/29040570#29040570) applies here. see also https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/140.

Comment: I find these pages useful https://gohugo.io/tutorials/mathjax/ and http://doswa.com/2011/07/20/mathjax-in-markdown.html